# Computing the Electric and Magnetic Field Distribution of a Funnel Waveguide

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, waveguide

In our undergraduate E&MWaves class, we learned about a rectangular waveguide, and how to calculate the electric and magnetic field distribution throughout the waveguide using finite element analysis. Out of curiosity, I am interested in how you would go about solving the boundary conditions of a funnel wave guide, as a series of rectangles that radially get larger and larger. Can each 'rectangle' be calculated separately, and 'stitched' together at the end? How do you figure out the boundary conditions of this waveguide?